# Caliburn.Micro ShowPopup - set focus

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm trying to use Caliburn.Micro (for my first WPF MVVM project) and I'm struggling with getting the WindowManager.ShowPopup method to set focus to the popup screen. Is this possible?  The sample HelloWindowManager from Caliburn doesn't do it either, and the documentation is pretty light.

Comment: Do you want your popup to be modal?

Comment: Wondering if calling `Focus` on one of the popups controls would work (I don't think there is a method to focus on the actual popup itself). If so you could just create some functionality to find an element by name on the view (using `IViewAware.GetView()`) and focus it after the VM has been instatiated.

Comment: I eventually got this working with a combination of ShowWindow (not ShowPopup) and also using the EventAggregator to publish an event to the called window's ViewModel... in there I set a property and used a DataTrigger on the view to set focus through the FocusManager. It may be a hack but it seems to work.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a hack to me - no reason that a view can't depend on a service such as the event aggregator and you are maintaining a nice segregation between viewmodel and view concerns - you should post as an answer and I'd vote that :)

Comment: wpf popup focus is a pain... even without caliburn itself, I can't get it to work... after calling `popup.IsOpen = true`, I've tried several approach to focus the first control within the popup, no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, I was unable to get the `ShowPopup` method to work as I wanted.

What I did instead was use `ShowWindow`, and then used the EventAggregator to publish an event when I was showing the window. In the ViewModel for the *called* View, I subscribed to that event, and set a property on the ViewModel to true (named KeywordEntryActive in this example).

I then use a Style on the Grid that uses a DataTrigger bound to that property to call the FocusManager.FocusedElement method in the View.

```
<Grid.Style>
    <Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding KeywordEntryActive}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=Command}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Grid.Style>
```

It seemed less straightforward than I hoped, but I was able to accomplish what I was looking for without sacrificing the separation of ViewModel and View, so I'm satisfied with it at this point. There's been a bit of a learning curve with Caliburn.Micro but so far I've been able to overcome the snags I've run into, and I'm continuing down this path.